# Replacing a string with special characters

Tags: unix

I am trying to replace a set of characters within a variable.

```
var1='&apos;abcd&apos;'
```

I want to replace ''' with a pipe so that it looks like.

> |abcd|

I have tried the below.

```
var1=$(sed 's/&apos;/|/g' <<< $var1)
```

But its not working. Could anyone kindly help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Original answer was for a incorrect formatted question.

This works

```
var1=$(echo "${var1}" | sed 's/&apos;/|/g')
```

Comment: Hi Walter, sorry I goofed up the question. I have now edited it.